# После активации виртуального окружения название самого окружения не появилось перед дерикторией в консоли

Tags: python, django

После активации виртуального окружения название самого окружения не появилось перед дерикторией в консоли VS CODE хотя должно было. Сначала я ввел в консоль python -m venv SHOP. Потом SHOP\Scripts\activate.bat . Никаких ошибок не последовало, но виртуальное окружение (SHOP) не появилось. В чем может быть проблема? Скрин кидать не вижу смысла, ведь там ничего нет.

Answer (score 0):

Удалите виртуальное окружение, создайте по новой. Лучше называть venv  или  virtualvenv. Делайте все те же действия

1. `python -m venv venv`
2. `cd/`в дерикторию где лежит venv
3. `venv\Scripts\activate.bat` - для Windows;
   `source venv/bin/activate` - для Linux и MacOS.

В виртуальном окружении вместо команды python3 и pip3, можно использовать python и pip

Закончив работу в виртуальной среде, вы можете отключить ее, выполнив консольную команду:

```
deactivate
```